# Printer setup asks for "address" and "queue"

Tags: kubuntu, printing

I'm trying to set up my Brother network printers on my Kubuntu 20.04 machine. I have installed one printer without a hitch, but when I try to install the other, I am asked to input an "address" and a "queue." [See screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViT2X.png)

What am I supposed to input for these fields? I have done several online searches, and none of what I found helps me.

Comment: For my Brother printers I've had best results going to their site, downloading the driver, and following instructions. I always have trouble with the GUI configuration. https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadtop.aspx?c=ca&lang=en&prod=mfcj870dw_us_eu_as

Comment: @StephenBoston, thanks for the suggestion. I did that and it worked, but if anyone else has an answer to this, I will still accept other answers.